# Using iCarousel to show image from directory

Tags: ios, directory, icarousel

I would want to show the image to from the directory.  In the directory I have made folders to store the pictures.   I am getting an error that is saying Use of undeclared identifier 'NSFileManagerdefaultManager' and Use of undeclared identifier 'documentsDirectory'; did you mean 'NSDocumentDirectory'? and Bad receiver type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int'). I can not get rid of this. I am trying but it just doesn't work.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel
    imageArray1 = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    NSString *location=@"Tops";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];

    imageArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    location=@"Bottoms";
    fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];

    directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray2 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];

    carousel1.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    carousel2.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some really wierd things in your code:

```
imageArray1 = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
```

Here you are casting an `NSArray` to a `NSMutableArray`, but it will still be an `NSArray`. You can't do this.

```
NSString *location=@"Tops";
NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];
```

Then you build the `fpath` string, which you where already using the first line. Here you are doing the the conversion to `NSMutableArray` correctly.

You just need to remove the first line, it is not needed and does nothing. Same goes for this line:

```
imageArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You are just create an empty array and then later you just assign an other array:

```
imageArray2 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];
```

Just remove the `imageArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` it is not necessary and will only use unnecessary memory.

This will work better:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //configure carousel
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tops"];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];

    //configure carouse2
    fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bottoms";];
    directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath:fPath];
    imageArray2 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];

    carousel1.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    carousel2.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was a great help.  Lastly one question I was tried to run it and the image does not show up. What code should possibly go wrong?

Comment: Not sure, since you did not post any thing to do with displaying the images. I think you will have to start a new question about this.

Comment: ok Thank you for everything.